# Why the SGDRegressor function in sklearn can't converge to the correct optima?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sgd

I was practicing using SGDRegressor in sklearn but I meet some problems, and I have simplified it as the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

X = np.array([0,0.5,1]).reshape((3,1))
y = np.array([0,0.5,1]).reshape((3,1))

sgd = SGDRegressor()  
sgd.fit(X, y.ravel())

print("intercept=", sgd.intercept_)
print("coef=", sgd.coef_)
```

And this is the output:

```
intercept= [0.19835632]
coef= [0.18652387]
```

All the outputs are around intercept=0.19 and coef=0.18, but obviously the correct answer is `intercept=0` and `coef=1`.
Even in this simple example, the program can't get the correct solution of the parameters. I wonder where I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With n=10000 data points (draw samples with replacement from your 3 original points) you get the following results with SGD

```
n = 10000

X = np.random.choice([0,0.5,1], n, replace=True)
y = X

X = X.reshape((n,1))

sgd = SGDRegressor(verbose=1)  
sgd.fit(X, y)

# -- Epoch 1
# Norm: 0.86, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.076159, T: 10000, Avg. loss: 0.012120
# Total training time: 0.04 seconds.
# -- Epoch 2
# Norm: 0.96, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.024337, T: 20000, Avg. loss: 0.000586
# Total training time: 0.04 seconds.
# -- Epoch 3
# Norm: 0.98, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.008826, T: 30000, Avg. loss: 0.000065
# Total training time: 0.04 seconds.
# -- Epoch 4
# Norm: 0.99, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.003617, T: 40000, Avg. loss: 0.000010
# Total training time: 0.04 seconds.
# -- Epoch 5
# Norm: 1.00, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.001686, T: 50000, Avg. loss: 0.000002
# Total training time: 0.05 seconds.
# -- Epoch 6
# Norm: 1.00, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.000911, T: 60000, Avg. loss: 0.000000
# Total training time: 0.05 seconds.
# -- Epoch 7
# Norm: 1.00, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.000570, T: 70000, Avg. loss: 0.000000
# Total training time: 0.05 seconds.
# Convergence after 7 epochs took 0.05 seconds

print("intercept=", sgd.intercept_)
print("coef=", sgd.coef_)
# intercept= [0.00057032]
# coef= [0.99892893]

plt.plot(X, y, 'r.')
plt.plot(X, sgd.intercept_ + sgd.coef_*X, 'b-')
```

[image]

The following animation shows how SGD regressor starts converging to the correct optima as n goes up in the above code:

[image]

Comment: What is the reason behind this nature of SGD? Why does it does not converges on less data?

Answer (score 0):

SGD (Stochastic Gradient Descent) is used for large scale data. For such a trivial amount I would advise you to use a simple Linear Regression instead. As stated by the "No Free Lunch Theorem", there is not one model fits all solution and hence you should often experiment with different models to find an optimal (however you should also be aware of the background of your data such as distribution types, diversity factor, skewness, etc.). Check out the below model instead:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X,y.ravel())
lr.predict([[0],[0.5],[1]])
# output -> array([1.11022302e-16, 5.00000000e-01, 1.00000000e+00])
```

Comment: I was trying to apply SGD to my dataset of 5000 data, and it doesn't work either. Maybe 5000 is also too small?

Comment: Not gonna lie, but probably a 50k data set should be the lowest numeric value for which you should be using it. Check out the difference between "stochastic" and "batch" gradient descents